# How prove for any positive integer numbers $n$ can define Sum of the some different terms of that sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

let positive integer sequence $\{a_{n}\}$,and such 
$$a_{1}=1,a_{k}\le 1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_{i},k\in N^{+},k\ge 2$$
show that: for any positive $n$ ,then
$n$ can define
 Sum of the some  different terms of that sequence

My idea: since $$a_{2}\le 1+a_{1}=2$$,then $a_{2}=1,2$
if $a_{2}=1,$ then $$a_{3}\le 1+a_{1}+a_{2}=3$$
so
$a_{3}=1$ or $2$,$3$

I guess this problem can use Mathematical induction to solve it.But I can't.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_m = \sum ^m_{i=1} a_i$. Pick some $m$ such that $n \leq S_m$. If $n < a_m$ then, because $a_m \leq 1 + S_{m-1}$ we have $n \leq S_{m-1}$. Otherwise, if $n \geq a_m$ then by definition of $m$ we have $n-a_m \leq S_{m-1}$.

Therefore, by including or excluding $a_m$ you can keep reducing $n$ and $m$ until you have $n_{remining} \leq S_1$. At that point $n_{remaining} = 0$ or $n_{remaining} = S_1 = 1$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

the optimal bound is $$
a_n\le 2^{n-1}
$$
Proof:

1. $2^0 = a_1$
2. if $\forall k<n\ \ a_k \le 2^{k-1}$ then
   $$
   a_n = a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 + 1\\
   \le 2^{n-2} + \cdots + 1 + 1\\
   =\frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2 - 1} + 1 =2^{n-1}
   $$

This is optimal because if there is equality at the beginning, then the same computation proves that there is equality everywhere.